# Conditionals at the top of a tikz subgraph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to use a conditional in graph with Tikz (awesome package by the way). My solution is to repeat the node with 2 different labels :

```
"Urgent ?" -> ["yes"] "do something";
"Urgent ?" ->["no"] "sleep";
```

Is there a syntax with subgraphs to have a shorter version ? Something like :

```
"Urgent" {
  -> ["yes"] "do something";
  ->["no"] "sleep";
}
```

Thanks !

Minimal working example :

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [layered layout]
{
  "Urgent ?"
  -> ["yes"] "do something";
  "Urgent ?"
  ->["no"] "sleep";
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `"Urgent ?" -> { "do something" [>"yes"], "sleep" [>"no"] };`

Comment: Perfect ! If you can post it as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in section 19.6.5 'Placing Node Texts on Incoming Edges' ('TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 3.0.1a' p280), using the `>` shorthand:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph [layered layout]
{
  "Urgent ?" -> { "do something" [>"yes"], "sleep" [>"no"] };
};
\end{document}
```

[image]